# Controlling Access to Official Repository in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is it possible in Bitbucket to restrict access to the official repository for developers, yet still allow them to branch and create pull requests?

I'd like to restrict write/pull access to a few senior team members, so they have control over the official repo, and not allow other devs to accidentally push to that repo.  Another benefit would be that it would force developers to branch each time they worked on a feature.

I'm new to git and bitbucket, so I'm open to other ideas on how to control this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the settings in https://bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}/admin/access?

I'm pretty sure if you set the user to read they can fork and create pull requests and then your seniors with the write permission could do the merging.